# How to write to an entry to a specific ROWID in SQLite db in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to know if it is  possible to write an entry to a specific ROWID  in android. This is my create Entry code.

```
public long createEntry(String cType, String siteName, String siteNum,
                       String username, String pass) {

    ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_CTYPE,cType);
    cv.put(KEY_SNAME,siteName);
    cv.put(KEY_SNUMB,siteNum);
    cv.put(KEY_USRN,username);
    cv.put(KEY_PASS,pass);
    //cv.put(KEY_EMPTY,0);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);
}
```

and this is how I create a table

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      //  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + KEY_CTYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                +  KEY_SNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                +  KEY_SNUMB + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                +  KEY_USRN + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                +  KEY_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                +  KEY_EMPTY + " INTEGER);"
        );
        /*for(int x=1;x<9;x++){
            createEntry("Account"+ String.valueOf(x),"","","","");

        }*/

    }
```

I would like to be able to create an entry at a specific ROWID. If its possible please guide me . I am new to android db .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think it's possible to SET the rowid before insert. Anyway, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have some accounts to save - these are 8 in total. if i am able to write to a specific row , it will make stuff easier for me as Account 1 will be saved in ROWID=1 and so on .

Comment: Suppose I have 6 accounts saved- and user deletes the 5th . Now when user adds a new account I want it to be writen to ROWID=5 instead of 7.

Comment: ROWID is system field, if there is some way to achieve this, I really suggest you NOT to do it. You have to manage ID field anyway, just do it in another, different from ROWID.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose I have 6 accounts saved- and user deletes the 5th . Now when
>   user adds a new account I want it to be writen to ROWID=5 instead of
>   7. – dmsherazi

Instead of opening a black hole for almost no reason, you may just mark your rows as deleted. Then, instead of creating new records, you can update "deleted" record and remove the "deleted" flag. With this, the ROWID will be the same all the time.

**OR**

you can manage your own ID field.

Comment: Can u please help me by giving example code? I am confused! :(

Comment: there is no example code for this. This is the way you should organize your database. If you mark your records as deleted, you should exclude them from all other selects you make (WHERE [DeletedFlag]=0). When you insert you check for a record with [DletedFlag]=1 and modify it instead of insert and SET [DeletedFlag]=0. If you manage your own id field you will have to check for "holes" in the whole table and set this id on your own